# Complex If Statements

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I need to write a long if statement for the loop I am doing in R to simulate football matches in a season. currently i'm using this code to simulate results of matches

```
mod3=glm(formula = Score ~ as.factor(Attack) + as.factor(Defence) +as.factor(Home)+Division, family = poisson,    data = football)
for (i in 1:92){
 for (j in 1:92){
  if (i!=j){
  teamHome=levels(football$Attack)[i] 
  teamAway=levels(football$Attack)[j]
  homeScore=rpois(1,predict.glm(mod3, data.frame(Attack=teamHome,Defence=teamAway,Home="Y   "),type="response"))
  awayScore=rpois(1,predict.glm(mod3, data.frame(Attack=teamAway,Defence=teamHome,Home="N   "),type="response"))
  Result= if(homeScore>awayScore){
   Result="H"
} else if(homeScore<awayScore){
Result="A"
}else if(homeScore==awayScore){
Result="D"
}


 results<-print(paste(teamHome,homeScore,"      ",teamAway,awayScore,Result),quote=F)
 }
}
}
```

Currently the attack,defence and home scores from my poisson regression help simulate the result. However I need to add another factor "Division" where if any of the top half(46) teams are simulated against eachother as "teamHome" and "teamAway" I return a "Division" response of "S" and if any of the bottom 46 teams are simulated against eachother I return the "division" response "S1". How would I encorporate this in my loop below are my levels for teamHome and teamAway for reference

```
 [1] "Manchester United     " "Manchester City       " "Chelsea               "
 [4] "Arsenal               " "Tottenham             " "Everton               "
  [7] "Liverpool             " "WBA                   " "Swansea               "
 [10] "West Ham              " "Norwich               " "Fulham                "
 [13] "Stoke                 " "Southampton           " "Aston Villa           "
 [16] "Newcastle             " "Sunderland            " "Wigan                 "
 [19] "Reading               " "QPR                   " "Cardiff               "
 [22] "Hull                  " "Watford               " "Brighton              "
 [25] "Crystal Palace        " "Leicester             " "Bolton                "
 [28] "Nottingham Forest     " "Charlton              " "Derby                 "
 [31] "Burnley               " "Birmingham            " "Leeds                 "
 [34] "Ipswich               " "Blackpool             " "Middlesbrough         "
 [37] "Blackburn             " "Sheffield Wednesday   " "Huddersfield          "
 [40] "Millwall              " "Barnsley              " "Peterborough          "
 [43] "Wolves                " "Bristol City          " "Doncaster             "
 [46] "Bournemouth           " "Brentford             " "Yeovil                "
 [49] "Sheffield United      " "Swindon               " "Leyton Orient         "
 [52] "Milton Keynes Dons    " "Walsall               " "Crawley               "
 [55] "Tranmere              " "Notts County          " "Crewe                 "
 [58] "Preston               " "Coventry              " "Shrewsbury            "
 [61] "Carlisle              " "Stevenage             " "Oldham                "
 [64] "Colchester            " "Scunthorpe            " "Bury                  "
 [67] "Hartlepool            " "Portsmouth            " "Gillingham            "
 [70] "Rotherham             " "Port Vale             " "Burton                "
 [73] "Cheltenham            " "Northampton           " "Bradford              "
 [76] "Chesterfield          " "Oxford                " "Exeter                "
 [79] "Southend              " "Rochdale              " "Fleetwood             "
 [82] "Bristol Rovers        " "Wycombe               " "Morecambe             "
 [85] "York                  " "Accrington            " "Torquay               "
 [88] "AFC Wimbledon         " "Plymouth              " "Dagenham and Redbridge"
 [91] "Barnet                " "Aldershot             "
```

If you feel you can help or anything is unclear about my explanation and needs explaining please ask as I am desperate for help on this.

example of the form of my dataset

```
Attack                Defence                    Score Home Division 
1 Chelsea                Aston Villa                8 Y    S                  
2 Arsenal                Reading                    4 N    S                 
3 Arsenal                Newcastle                  7 Y    S                
4 Port Vale              Burton                     7 Y    S                  
5 Liverpool              Newcastle                  6 N    S                  
6 Watford                Leeds                      6 N    S
```

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Could you not just initialise `division <- factor("neither", levels=c("S","S1","neither")` and then set `if (max(i,j)<=46) division[1] <- "S"` and `if (min(i,j)>46) division[1] <- S1`  It's not clear what you want division to be the case when teams are not from the same half of the table.   Also, item 7 in your list appears in the wrong place ;)

Comment: @GavinKelly Hi Gavin, thanks for the response I was trying to use the top half, bottom half as an example to get the idea of the if statement needed because not sure most people would understand the football tables. But in reality I do also need a division response where the top 20 play against the 20-44 e.g Premier League and Championship and all the other combinations between the leagues. any idea how that would be formatted ? sorry about liverpools placing i'm using last years data !!

Comment: @mvw Top half would mean the first 46 teams in the output shown above

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve - your `football$Division` (in your glm call) presumably contains which part of which division each team is in (if not, `football$Division=cut(rankOfTeam, breaks=c(0,46,...))` will do it. If you're trying to include a predictive term for how teams in a part of a division perform against others in the same or different halves, then you'll need both home- and away- division terms in your model. May be sparsity issues if trying to predict over newly-promoted teams, and model-rank issues.  `head(football)` might help us understand.

Comment: @GavinKelly basically Division is a predictive term for how teams perform between leagues. My levels for Division are 
       [1] "12      " "1C      " "1P      " "21      " "2C      " "2P      "
      [7] "C1      " "C2      " "CP      " "P1      " "P2      " "PC         "
     [13] "S       " There being 4 leagues P,C,1 and 2 and a rating for how each team attacks against a team from another league. I am trying to simulate matches between all 92 teams therefore I am using these factors to help simulating matches between divisions

Comment: So if you have just one _division_ entry per row of _football_, but there are necessarily two teams, the _division_ must relate to either the attack or defence.  So the coefficients in mod3 will be the average goal difference over teams in that part of the league? To access it in your loop, `division <- football$division[football$Attack == teamHome][1]` should give you this if division is tethered to the attacking team, for example.  If you want a term that predicts eg how 1P typically perform against 2C, then you'll need a factor in _football_ for the attack:defence term "1P:2C"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore my final comment to the original post - I now see from your example that you've got two divisions in each row,concatenated into a single string.  So you could extract the relevant within-division label as:

```
homeDiv <- substr(football$division[football$Attack==teamHome][1], 1, 1)
awayDiv <- substr(football$division[football$Attack==teamAway][1], 1, 1)
homeScore <- rpois(..., data.frame(..., division = sprintf("%s%s", homeDiv, awayDiv) ...) ...)
```

so the first line extracts the first character of an arbitrary (I've chosen the first - but they should all have the same first characters) row where the the attacking team is the chosen home team.  Similarly for the away team.  We then concatenate them to get the relevant home:away division contrast

Comment: Hi Gavin, R is failing to recognise the string value for Division.        with the coefficients found in mod2   Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor Division has new level SS

Comment: So I'm guessing _S_ represents any within-division match, whereas _P1_ denotes a between division. Could you try `ind <- nchar(football$division)!=1` before the three lines.  Then change `==teamHome` to `==teamHome & ind`, and similarly insert `& ind` on the next line.  Finally, before the homeScore assignment, add the line `if(homeDiv==AwayDiv) {homeDiv <- "S"; awayDiv <-""}`.

Comment: You're going to have problems if, in your old data, two teams neither played anyone from another division (as your data will not enable us to detect their division easily), but then go on to play each other in the new season.  If this occurs, you may be able to infer a team's division by teams which it has played against (or you can look it up!)

Comment: Hi, when I do ind <- nchar(football$division)!=1 I recieve logical(0) therefore it turns division into NANA. Could there be a problem with the way Division is entered in the data ?

Comment: I do have a divisional effect for each combination

Comment: Maybe try `nchar(as.character(football$Division))!=1` - and check it wasn't simply the capitalisation of  _division_